# How to abstract (with Func?) part of the function

Tags: c#, .net

in my DAL with Dapper I have loads of repeating code:

```
using (var sqlConn = new NpgsqlConnection("..."))
{
    sqlConn.Open();
    // query
}
```

Figuring out how to abstract queries that return nothing was easy:

```
    private void OpenConn(Action<NpgsqlConnection> action)
    {
        using (var sqlConn = new NpgsqlConnection("...")
        {
            sqlConn.Open();
            action.Invoke(sqlConn);
        }
    }
```

And you just call it like that:

```
OpenConn(x => x.Execute("INSERT INTO ..."));
```

But I have no idea how to rewrite OpenConn function, so that you could return results from it, ie inside another function to return int:

```
public int Example() {
    return OpenConn<int>(x => x.Query<int>("...").First());
}
```

or

```
public int Example() {
    OpenConn<int>(x => return x.Query<int>("...").First());
}
```

?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps something like this:

```
private TResult OpenConn<TResult>(Func<NpgsqlConnection, TResult> query)
{
    using (var sqlConn = new NpgsqlConnection("...")
    {
        sqlConn.Open();
        return query(sqlConn);
    }
}
```

Call:

```
public int Example() 
{
    return OpenConn<int>(x => return x.Query<int>("...").First());
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Define an overload for OpenCon with this syntax.

```
public int OpenConn(Func<NpgsqlConnection, int> func)
{
    using (var sqlConn = new NpgsqlConnection("...")
    {
        sqlConn.Open();
        return func(sqlConn);
    }
}
```

OpenConn now receives as parameter a delegate to a function that receives a connection and returns an integer.

And you call it returning the result of your query out of OpenCon

```
public int Example() 
{
   int result = OpenConn(x => return x.Query<int>("...").First());
}
```